# How do I get particular location of google map in center in android studio?

Tags: android

Is there any solution to get only India map in center and not other countries. I want to show India map only.

help me

how can I use my own marker and reduce its size?

how do I zoom particular location when I click on the marker?

**Below is the code**

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(24.000, 82.000);
   // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Marker in india"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 4.3f));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(){

    if(mMap!=null)
    {
        setUpMap();
    }

}

private void setUpMap() {
    Marker sikkim = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(27.2925, 88.3594)).title("Nit Sikkim"));
    Marker delhi = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(28.384764, 77.3037229)).title("Nit Delhi"));
    Marker patna = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(25.6207, 85.1729)).title("Nit Patna"));
    Marker calicut = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(28.384764, 77.3037229)).title("Nit Calicut"));
    Marker silcher = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(24.7574, 92.7854)).title("Nit Silcher"));
    Marker warangle = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(17.9808,79.5328)).title("Nit Warangle"));
    Marker durgapur = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.5483,87.2914)).title("Nit Durgapur"));
    Marker srinagar = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(34.1250,74.8397)).title("Nit Srinagar"));
    Marker trichy = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.763,78.818)).title("Nit Trichy"));
    Marker rourkela = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(22.2492,82.9161)).title("Nit Rourkela"));
    Marker agartala = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.9667,91.4167)).title("Nit Agartala"));
    Marker allahabad = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(25.4918,81.8658)).title("MNNit Allahabad"));
    Marker bhopal = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.2156,77.4083)).title("Nit bhopal"));
    Marker jaipur = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(26.8622,75.8156)).title("Nit Jaipur"));
    Marker hamirpur = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(31.7070,76.5263)).title("Nit hamirpur"));
    Marker jalandhar = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(31.3976,75.5349)).title("Nit Jalandhar"));
    Marker jamshedpur = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(22.7767,86.1489)).title("Nit Jamshedpur"));
    Marker kurushetra = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(29.9491,76.8173)).title("Nit Kurushetra"));
    Marker nagpur = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(21.1233,79.0516)).title("VNit Nagpur"));
    Marker raipur = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(21.2478,81.6039)).title("Nit Raipur"));
    Marker surat = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(21.1646, 72.7852)).title("Nit Surat"));
    Marker surathkal = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.0092, 74.7937)).title("Nit Surathkal"));
    Marker aurnachal = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(27.1498, 93.7170)).title("Nit Arunachal Prasad"));
    Marker goa = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(15.4225,73.9799)).title("Nit Goa"));
    Marker nagaland = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(25.7878,93.7744)).title("Nit Nagaland"));
    Marker mizoram = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.7484, 92.7208)).title("Nit Mizoram"));
    Marker uttrakhand = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.1968, 78.8227)).title("Nit Uttrakhand"));
    Marker pondicherry = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.9391,79.8317)).title("Nit Pondicherry"));

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder=new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    builder.include(sikkim.getPosition());
    builder.include(delhi.getPosition());
    builder.include(patna.getPosition());
    builder.include(calicut.getPosition());
    builder.include(silcher.getPosition());
    builder.include(warangle.getPosition());
    builder.include(durgapur.getPosition());
    builder.include(srinagar.getPosition());
    builder.include(trichy.getPosition());
    builder.include(rourkela.getPosition());
    builder.include(agartala.getPosition());
    builder.include(allahabad.getPosition());
    builder.include(bhopal.getPosition());
    builder.include(jaipur.getPosition());
    builder.include(hamirpur.getPosition());
    builder.include(jalandhar.getPosition());
    builder.include(jamshedpur.getPosition());
    builder.include(kurushetra.getPosition());
    builder.include(nagpur.getPosition());
    builder.include(raipur.getPosition());
    builder.include(surat.getPosition());
    builder.include(surathkal.getPosition());
    builder.include(aurnachal.getPosition());
    builder.include(goa.getPosition());
    builder.include(nagaland.getPosition());
    builder.include(mizoram.getPosition());
    builder.include(uttrakhand.getPosition());
    builder.include(pondicherry.getPosition());
```

}
}

Comment: By "*only India map in center and not other countries*" you mean, that the Map when zoomed out is just India, then that's impossible.. Unless you do a checker where you restrict the map for zooming out or going out of the bounds of India.. If you mean that you just want the map to start overseeing India, just specify the `LatLng` coordinates and the zoom value, like in @Stallion's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you can not do this because map is always showing as full view of world region you can not limit it but as like you require focus only specific region you can [for more specific answer read this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13250211/3514144)  ,and particular from your problem it's seems like add multiple [marker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35770711/3514144) you can get reference from that link

Comment: I tried to focus camera in specific position but its not working when I put 30 markers simultaneously.                                                                                                              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(33.7167, 73.0667), 4));                                                                                                                          I didn't get it in correct position.

Comment: Ok so its like you are facing problem with multiple marker and show focus on it.

Comment: ya.  I tried this one also but too many logcat errors ocurred.    Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(27.2925, 88.3594)).title(" Sikkim "));                                                                           LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

            builder.include(marker1.getPosition());

Comment: check my updated answer for how you can add multiple marker on map

Comment: when I open the app....all markers should be visible. I don't want to add marker after getting location becoz marker will show only in the current location.

Comment: hey tell me, how to fix E/Internal: device offline.

Comment: help me for finding solution